# Is there a parameterize function in PostgreSQL like in Ruby?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql

In Ruby, there's a very useful function on string objects which will take a string and parameterize the characters in that string so that can be used in a URL. i.e.:

```
2.2.2 :001 > "Rising Star".parameterize
  => "rising-star"
```

Is there a comparable function in SQL which will perform this same function on a string?

Use case:

I need to write an SQL script which will do something like the following:

```
UPDATE companies SET unique_permalink = id + name;
```

If there was a parameterize function in SQL, I would expect I could do the following:

```
UPDATE companies SET unique_permalink = id + parameterize(name);
```

However, I can't find any kind of function which will perform the operation I need it to perform. Has anyone tackled this challenge before who could help me out?

Much thanks friends!

Comment: Ruby has the function, so why not do this in Ruby? Your Postgres might have V8 support, so you could *theoretically* port it to JavaScript if you wanted, but that sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: I do have a script which performs this function in Ruby, however, this script will take >12 hours to run on my production dataset. I've seen this problem quite a bit on many projects and would rather create much faster SQL scripts/commands to get production datasets to clean states as fast as possible. Ruby scripts are great, but when you have an ORM siting over a DB it's actually quite slow compared to lower level database scripts. I really want to find a way to solve that problem.

Comment: As far as I know Postgresql does not have such native function but you can mimic it by using concatenation and regex replace function.

Comment: There's a lot of options for [procedural languages in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/xplang.html), so you could experiment with [pl-ruby](https://github.com/knu/postgresql-plruby). That seems rather drastic for a one-time thing, mind you.

Comment: I'm not sure if `regexp_replace(lower(name), ' ', '-')` would do it, but you never know.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses!

tadman, I am trying to find some reusable patterns for my team to use in future scripts as well so it might not be overkill to figure this out. I am going to check out pl-ruby.

As for the regex option, I thought about that but there are a lot of unicode values in the data I need to parameterize so I would basically have to just create a parameterize function myself in SQL in order to do this. That might not be a bad option though lol!

Comment: While not exactly the same, but you could try [pgURI extension](https://github.com/petere/pguri) that will url encode your string. `select uri_escape('Rising Star'); --Rising%20Star`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution I found to this problem isn't 100% the answer I was looking for, however, it's a massive performance improvement over any alternatives I could find or figure out.

```
connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
Company.all.find_in_batches do |companies|
  cases = companies.map{|c| "UPDATE companies set unique_permalink = {c.id}-#{c.name.parameterize}' where id = #{c.id}"}
  query = cases.join('; ')
  connection.execute(query)
end
```

The performance boost of this solution comes from batching a massive amount of queries in a single SQL statement. It's very performant and took a large process and made it super fast. Hopefully this helps someone out there.